# WPF Button remove "blur" from button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi  I'm trying to personalizate the button in  my wpf
cause when user is mousing over the button it shows the "default style"
as in this image bellow

[image]

As I don't want to show the deful blue and border element when Mouse is over in a  button, then I created this style to my button

```
<Style x:Key="Simple" TargetType="Button">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#399bff" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0"></DropShadowEffect>
                    </Border.Effect>

                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

                        <Path SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="9" Height="16.5" Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16.5,0,0,0"  Opacity="0">

                        </Path>
                        <Path SnapsToDevicePixels="True" x:Name="PathIcon" Width="8" Height="15"  Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,0,0,0">

                        </Path>

                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But it is creating some kind of blur or border in my button as  you  can see in the
NF-e button (left Blue one)  in this image

[image]

It should be as in the CT-e button (right orange one)

What is wrong with  my XAML style ?

**Edit**

The button XAML code

```
<Border  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10 10 5 5" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="150" Background="#992086bf" CornerRadius="10">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource Simple}" Click="GoToNFeEntrada" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <Grid Width="150" Height="150">
                <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="File" Width="50" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 30 0 0"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10 0 0 5" FontSize="15" Foreground="White">NF-e</Label>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </Border>
```

Comment: no, I  just removed this from the Style and it keeps showing this gray thing

Comment: Can you please show your content binding for the buttons? Everything looks fine and could easily be that button is set different from the others. EDIT: Yea, I thought you were triggering mouseover until I saw your first image had the same issue.

Comment: @TyCobb I updated the answer withing the button code

Comment: but I guess it is something  with the style cause before I use it, it was ok

Comment: Are the rest of the buttons also using Label? I don't see anything crazy.

Comment: Thank  you  @TyCobb for trying to  help me,  I didn't notice the line which  applies the effect  DropShadowEffect in the content so  I removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was removing this line

```
<Border.Effect>
     <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0"></DropShadowEffect>
</Border.Effect>
```

This effecting was creating some border in the content

Comment: Wouldn't all of the buttons have the same effect though?

Comment: Yes, but I did applied just for one button, now I'll apply the style to the others

Comment: I was under the impression that all of the buttons were using that style...

Comment: No, I was showing that  the button had the "default" style, and  that I wrote a code to change it but it was covering the content with this border effect